# ¿como poner campos en una tabla php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, adminlte

estoy tratando de hacer un horario de clases en PHP con MySQL ya tengo el horario creado pero tengo problemas al tratar de acomodarlo en la tabla.

aquí esta la consulta que hago y como muestro el nombre de la materia, (por el momento me muestra las materias de todos los días en el campo del martes) quiero saber como poner ahí las que sean solo del martes, no se si me explique, tal vez sea un tema de lógica, si me pueden orientar de antemano gracias.

```
               <table id="example3" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                  
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>lunes</th>
                    <th>Martes</th>
                    <th>Miercoles</th>
                    <th>Jueves</th>
                    <th>Viernes</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
  
 <tbody id="myTable">

      <?php 
            
            $sql="SELECT ma.id_materia, ma.nombre_materia,cu.nombre_curso,di.nombre_dia
                            from materia_profesor AS mp, materias AS ma, profesor AS pr, cursos AS cu , dias AS di, salon AS sa
                        where mp.id_materia = ma.id_materia
                        AND mp.id_profesor = pr.id_profesor
                        AND mp.id_curso = cu.id_curso
                        AND mp.id_dia = di.id_dia
                        AND mp.id_salon = sa.id_salon    
            AND mp.id_curso = '$id_mod2'
            order by di.id_dia asc";


            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or trigger_error($db->error);

            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           ?> 
  <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><?php echo $mostrar ['nombre_materia'] ?></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          
            
     
                  </tr>
                    


                     <?php } ?>  


               </tbody>

                </table>
```

así es como queda hasta ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es ta tabla en mysql, la estoy trabajando con los id donde lunes es 1, martes 2, miercoles3, etc..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias subir la una captura con la tabla? y recuerda que la iteracion debes hacerla dentro del while

Comment: @JhonnattanRivera ya la edite, gracias.

Comment: @JhonnattanRivera La recomendación siempre es compartir las cosas como texto para que quienes intentan responder puedan intentar replicar la cosa.

Comment: Estás creando la tabla y dentro del ciclo solo llenas la segunda celda (TD), que corresponde a Martes. Deberías analizar el valor de `id_dia` para saber dónde colocar la materia. Tampoco estás considerando los horarios.

Comment: @Triby lo estaba llenando en la segunda como manera de prueba, si lo pongo en todas me van a salir todas las materias en todas las columnas, tengo claro el valor del id_dia, pero ahí esta mi pregunta como debo ponerlo para acomodar cada materia en su lugar, no se si en el td debo poner algo mas, no se me ocurre como debo hacerlo, gracias.

Comment: Regresa al algoritmo, porque si solucionas solo lo del día, te va a quedar una fila por cada materia en el día que corresponda y, cuando llegues a los horarios, probablemente te veas en mayores problemas.

Comment: Sugerencia: Crea un arreglo donde el índice sean las horas de inicio y contenga 5 elementos (1 por día). Llena el arreglo al ejecutar la consulta y, cuando ya tengas todo armado, entonces sí haces la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es optimizar un poco la consulta:

- Genera la consulta sobre la tabla donde realmente está toda la información, que es `materia_profesor`, porque de `materias` solo tomas el nombre
- No es necesario teclear `AS` para especificar el alias de cada tabla, aunque sí puede ser conveniente para tener un código más legible, pero es cuestión de preferencias
- Especifica solo campos y tablas que realmente vayas a usar
- Para el resto de tablas usa alguna de las opciones de [`JOIN`](https://guru99.es/joins/)

  - Para este ejemplo seleccioné `LEFT` porque interesa **obtener todas las filas de la tabla primaria** y, de no existir correspondencia en las otras tablas, se asignarán valores nulos a los campos
  - Otro tipo de `JOIN` podría omitir filas si no hay correspondencia y, algún otro, obtener filas de todas las tablas, con probabilidad de registros duplicados. Deberás realizar pruebas para ver cuál satisface tus necesidades
  - Hay tablas que creo no es necesario unir para esta consulta, como *cursos* y *dias*, porque es información que ya deberías tener lista
  - Hay otros campos que, seguramente, usarás conforme vayas realizando pruebas, como `nombre_profesor`
  - Se realiza un filtro de cada tabla unida con la condición `ON`
- El filtro `WHERE` se realiza solo sobre campos de la tabla principal
- Ordena los resultados, primero por hora, después por día. No es necesario especificar el orden `ASC`, porque es el valor por defecto; también esto es cuestión de preferencias

```
    $sql = "SELECT mp.id_materia, mp.id_profesor, mp.id_curso, mp.hora_inicial, mp.id_dia,
            ma.nombre_materia,
            pr.nombre_profesor, 
            cu.nombre_curso
        FROM materia_profesor mp
        LEFT JOIN materias ma
            ON mp.id_materia = ma.id_materia
        LEFT JOIN profesor pr
            ON mp.id_profesor = pr.id_profesor
        LEFT JOIN cursos cu
            ON mp.id_curso = cu.id_curso
        WHERE mp.id_curso = '$id_mod2'
        ORDER by mp.hora_inicial, mp.id_dia";
```

Ahora viene la parte interesante: Crear un arreglo previo con estructura que permita llenar la tabla fácilmente:

```
    // Crear arreglo para armar horario
    $horario = [];
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or trigger_error($db->error);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Verificar que existe hora_inicial en arreglo
        $hora = $row['hora_inicial'];
        if(!isset($horario[$hora])) {
            // Crear arreglo con 5 elementos, uno para cada día
            $horario[$hora] = ['', '', '', '', ''];
        }
        // Agregar materia a $hora, en espacio correspondiente
        // Los índices de arreglo inician en cero, van de cero = lunes a 4 = viernes
        // Por eso el - 1
        $horario[$hora][$row['id_dia'] - 1] = $row['nombre_materia'];
    }
```

El resultado sería algo como:

```
$horario = [
    '08:00:00' => [
        'Materia del lunes',
        'Materia del martes',
        'Materia del miércoles',
        'Materia del jueves',
        'Materia del viernes'
    ],
    // Otros horarios y, al final:
    '13:00:00' => [
        'Materia del lunes',
        'Materia del martes',
        'Materia del miércoles',
        'Materia del jueves',
        'Materia del viernes'
    ],
];
```

Como ves, es prácticamente la estructura de la tabla, solo falta generar el HTML:

```
<?php
        // Crear encabezado de tabla
?>
        <table id="example3" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Hora</th>
                <th>lunes</th>
                <th>Martes</th>
                <th>Miercoles</th>
                <th>Jueves</th>
                <th>Viernes</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<?php
        // Llenar tabla
        foreach($horario as $hora => $dias) {
            echo <<<HTML
            <tr>
                <td>$hora</td>
                <td>{$dias[0]}</td>
                <td>{$dias[1]}</td>
                <td>{$dias[2]}</td>
                <td>{$dias[3]}</td>
                <td>{$dias[4]}</td>
            </tr>
HTML; // Esta línea debe estar en la primera columna, sin espacios ni tabuladores previos
        }
        // Cerrar tabla
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Notas:**

- En el ciclo para llenar la tabla estoy usando la estructura [HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), te recomiendo analizarla y entenderla antes de usarla, de lo contrario, una indentación del identificador de cierre te va a generar errores.
- De acuerdo a la tabla mostrada en imagen, tienes errores en horarios, asegúrate de corregirlos, porque supongo que no hay clases a las 00:00:00 o 01:00:00